# How to create a three dimensional array from sql query PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 tables in a database, 1 of them are linked with a foreign key to the first one. Each row on table 1 is linked to multiple rows in table 2. I am trying to make a query that looks at a `WHERE` from table 2 and returns multiple rows from table 2 which are sorted into the rows they linked with in table 1 and then put this all into one big multi dimensional array, so it should work something like this:

`$array[0][column_name][0]` this would use row 1 from table 1 and give me a the first result in the column called `column_name`
`$array[1][column_name][0]` this would use row 2 from table 1 and give me a the first result in the column called `column_name`
`$array[1][column_name][3]` this would use row 2 from table 1 and give me a the 4th result in the column called `column_name`
etc

How can I query this and store it in a 3 dimensional array using PHP.

I have tried to word this in as clear manner as possible, if you are unsure what I am asking, please comment and I will update my question to make it clearer.

Comment: It sounds like you’re going to try to do something in php that the database is much better suited to do... but if you look at the results of your query (showing all fields of both tables), a pattern should present itself. You could probably use the primary keys as the array indexes. I’m honestly not following what you’re trying to do because it sounds way more complicated than it should be. Remember, someone’s going to have to maintain this thing!

Comment: @TimMorton no, these tables have no patterns, I want to do the query in SQL and then put the results into a PHP array, but im not sure how to do that for a 3 dimensional array, for a 2 dimensional array I just use ```$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)```

Comment: could you give about 10 rows of results in your question?  To achieve your goal with the array, you will have to use the db primary keys as keys of an associative array; that’s the only way you’ll be able to track the “table1 row”.  Otherwise you’ll end up incrementing the first index with every db row.

Comment: It would probably be much easier to envision if you think of it as an array of arrays. The outer array represents each row of table 1, and the value stored in each array position is an array of the matching table 2’s rows.

Comment: @TimMorton that is precisely what I am asking about, how I would go about making this array of arrays

Comment: mysql will always provide a flat array. So to avoid repeating rows you either have to manpulate the array in PHP or perform two different queries and build the array. IMHO the second solution is preferrable in terms of speed of processing the data but both are valid

Comment: @LelioFaieta I just created the array using 2 different queries (the second one loops according to how many results come from the first) it is working as expected, but I think their is probably a better way of doing this

Comment: Updated my answer to show a single query solution to help answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that we have two tables, Company and Employee:

```
  Company
------------------
ID   Company_Name
 1    Walmart
 2    Amazon.com
 3    Apple

       Employee
---------------------------------       
ID Company_Id Employee_Name
 1         1   Sam Walton
 2         1   Rob Walton
 3         1   Jim Walton
 4         1   Alice Walton
 5         2   Jeff Bezos
 6         2   Brian T. Olsavsky
 7         3   Steve Jobs
 8         3   Tim Cook
```

The easiest way to envision a multi-dimensional (nested) array is to mimic the looping required to get it:  outer loop is the company, inner loop is the employees:

```
// ignoring database access, this is just pseudo code

$outer = [];
// select id, company_name from company
foreach $companyResult as $companyRow {

    // select * from employee where company_id = ?  {$companyRow['id']}
    $inner= [];
    foreach $employee_result as $employeeRow {
        $inner[] = $employeeRow;  // ie, ['id'=>'1','Company_Id'=>'1','Employee_Name'=>'Sam Walton']
    }

    $outer[] = $inner;
}

print_r($outer);

// yields ====>

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [Company_Id] => 1
                    [Employee_Name] => Sam Walton
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [Company_Id] => 1
                    [Employee_Name] => Rob Walton
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [Company_Id] => 1
                    [Employee_Name] => Jim Walton
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [Company_Id] => 1
                    [Employee_Name] => Alice Walton
                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [Company_Id] => 2
                    [Employee_Name] => Jeff Bezos
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [Company_Id] => 2
                    [Employee_Name] => Brian T. Olsavsky
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [Company_Id] => 3
                    [Employee_Name] => Steve Jobs
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 8
                    [Company_Id] => 3
                    [Employee_Name] => Tim Cook
                )

        )

)
```

---

It is also possible to do if you use associative arrays.  Consider the flat file that this query produces:

```
select company.id company_id, company.name company_name, 
       emp.id employee_id, emp.employee_name
from company 
inner join employee on company.id = employee.company_id

-----

    company_id company_name employee_id employee_name
            1       Walmart           1        Sam Walton
            1       Walmart           2        Rob Walton
            1       Walmart           3        Jim Walton
            1       Walmart           4      Alice Walton
            2    Amazon.com           5        Jeff Bezos
            2    Amazon.com           6 Brian T. Olsavsky
            3         Apple           7        Steve Jobs
            3         Apple           8          Tim Cook
```

Just use the primary IDs as the keys for your arrays:

```
$employeeList = [];
foreach($result as $row) {

  $cid = $row['company_name'];
  $eid = $row['employee_name'];
  // avoid uninitialized variable
  // $employeeList[$row['company_name']] = $employeeList[$row['company_name']] ?? [];

  // easier to read version of above
  $employeeList[$cid] = $employeeList[$cid] ?? [];

  // assign it...
  $employeeList[$cid][$eid] = $row;
}
```

Or, if you simply want each company row to hold an array of employee names,

```
  $employeeList[$cid][] = $row['employee_name'];
```

The way that I've shown you is useful if you know the company_id and want to find the associated rows:

```
foreach($employeeList[2] as $amazon_guys) { ... }
```

But it's not at all useful if you're trying to group by employee, or some other field in the employee table.  You'd have to organize the order of your indexes by your desired search order.

In the end, it's almost always better to simply do another query and let the database give you the specific results you want.